# What is the best way to manage memory used by strings in a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management, memory-leaks, unset

In PHP, I'm using an array to create the content of the HTML web-pages of my site.  I am also using Symfony 2, but not twig.  This is a example that creates a simple semi-unique page:

```
$strMAINs = [];

$r          = rand( 1, 99999 ); // $r needs to be generated on the server for some
                                // reason, so can't generated by the client and then
                                // sent back when the form that contains this code is
                                // submitted.  Why isn't important.

$strMAINs[] = '<table>';
$strMAINs[] =   '<tr>';
$strMAINs[] =     '<td>';
$strMAINs[] =       'Input a number from 1 to 99,999:';
$strMAINs[] =     '</td>';
$strMAINs[] =     '<td>';

                    // Create a random default value ...
$strMAINs[] =       '<input id="TextInput" value="' . $r . '" />';

$strMAINs[] =     '</td>';
$strMAINs[] =   '</tr>';
$strMAINs[] = '</table>';

$strMAIN = implode( PHP_EOL, $strMAINs );

// Note, in my web-app the strings can be a lot longer.

// Send the content $strMAIN to the browser using the appropriate Symfony 2 function.
```

At this point I can let Symfony/PHP release/reclaim the memory used by the $strMAIN string and the $strMAINs array strings when the parent function that owns these variables exits and let the garbage collector deal with the memory on it's own, or use the unset command on the $strMAINs array, but not $strMAIN because it needs its value for the Symfony function that sends the page to the browser.

However, from what I read about the unset command, it seems that the variables in the unset command do release their memory, but it isn't necessarily available to another user of my site until the garbage collector gets around to doing its job.

I'm also concerned about memory leaks.

While looking at the PHP unset command, I saw that setting the array to NULL might cause the memory to be released and available faster.

Comment: That's how automatic memory management works. No matter how you free the data, it doesn't become available until the GC cleans it up. Don't worry about it, the GC will run when it's needed.

Comment: As far as memory management is concerned, it doesn't matter if you use `unset`, assign `null`, or go out of scope of the variable. It's still the garbage collector's responsibility to reclaim the memory.

Comment: PHP uses reference counting, so data without circular reference possibilities can be reclaimed immediately when the references are destroyed, it doesn't have to wait for GC. And strings can't be circularly referenced.